# How should I cross compile zxing for ARM?

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling, zxing

Like normal people I work in an x86 environment, unfortunately all I know of CMAKE is to auto-detect and build for the compiling environment.

Like many open source projects it has a relatively large CMakeLists.txt, with the amount of settings that beyond reasonable to go through unless you are contributing.

Is there a way to quickly specify a target environment, processor and all the things without digging all the way down to the build scripts and source codes?

It could be simple as some cmake parameters, but I am quite new to it... could really use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up a cross compile toolchain and create a corresponding CMake toolchain file.

See:   http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

Depending on the ARM platform you are working with, it can be fairly easy or incredibly difficult to set up such an environment.

As an example below is the cross compile toolchain setup guide for cross compiling Qt5 for the raspberry pi.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide

Comment: I should mention that I already have the vendor provided environment toolchain, but I have no clue on whether editing the already complicated CMakeLists.txt or just some `-D`s.

Comment: Usually its enough to override elements in a toolchain file.  Override the location of the C compiler, the C++ compiler, find path root, etc.  Out of curiosity, which board are you working on?

Comment: just got it working, I must say that people should avoid cross-compiling directly on Mac... I setup an Arch VM and did it nice and clean. It's a custom board with an ARM926EJS processor.

Comment: VMs are the way to do it. Ubuntu 10.04 is still my favorite for this purpose.

Comment: I am kinda minimalist, and Arch boots in like 10 secs even in VM, which feels just great. :D